# How can we use multithreading in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

React Native is single-threaded. So, In its rendering rather than have multiple processes occur at the same time (multithreading), other components have to wait when one component is being rendered. How can we handle the multithreading limitations in react-native?

Is there anyone? who has the sample code? If someone did this before.

Comment: Note that React Native is not alone in having a single-threaded GUI system. Android development is the same. As is the Windows API, Gnome's GTK, MacOS Quartz and indeed all other GUI libraries out there. Multithreading is for algorithms you need to execute. GUI updates need to be synchronized to the UI thread (most of the time this is the main thread but not always, Windows and GTK for example can be programmed with the UI thread running not on the main thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using maintainable extensions, it handles multithreading in React Native App. An extension lets you provide an app with custom functionality that it would otherwise not have. It can be built  using Java, Swift or Objective C. Example of maintainable extensions creating a bridge between React Native and Native Components. I hope it explains a bit.

Comment: To add on further, here's [an article](https://blog.logrocket.com/overcoming-single-threaded-limitations-in-react-native/) we can read through. There're also some solutions on github which helps RN to spawn new processes to handle your work, take a look [this library](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads)